# OSGI bundle not found

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We are running Domino 8.5.3 FP6 on a linux box. We can't get any xpages sites contorl links to work and are getting "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error" in firebug.  There is nothing in the xpages log but this is in our startup.log:

```
!SESSION 2015-02-03 14:05:44.523 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 jvmxi3260sr16-20141010_216764 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20141010_216764
JIT  - r9_20140523_64469ifx2
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20141010_1202_B216764
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -noSplash true true true
Command-line arguments:  -console -data /home/notes/data/domino/workspace -noSplash true -clean true -noExit true

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-03 14:05:44.524
!MESSAGE Bundle com.ibm.domino.osgi.core@15 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2015-02-03 14:05:46.856
!MESSAGE /home/notes/data/domino/workspace/.config/domino/eclipse/plugins/plugins is not a valid plugins directory.
```

I have removed the old dojo-1.5.1 directory but this didn't change anything.  Permissions are set correctly in the server document.  I even removed the workspace directory and reinstalled FP6 to see if that would fix it.  Anyone seen this or know what it means?

Comment: This is a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/28195300/2065611

Comment: This is actually a question that came out of that discussion but I thought was different enough, and not answered.  I've about given up because I can't find anyone who has had this issue.  I apologize if I should not have started a new question.